# in AWS CDK, do I need to explicitly state that a service def has a LB attached to it?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

so I'm getting this message

> Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: UpdateService error: Health check grace period is only valid for services configured to use load balancers (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 91a0; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: 1eb3, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Ok, this error makes sense. The Fargate service that I've set up needs to have a load balancer attached. The thing is, I've already attached a load balancer to it?

```
    self.fargate_service_definition = ecs.FargateService(self, 'Service Def',
      cluster=self.cluster,
      task_definition=self.fargate_host_definition,
      service_name=f'{resource_name_prefix}-resource',
      vpc_subnets=subnets.private_subnet_selection,
      security_groups=[security_groups.corp_security_group],
    )
```

this is my service definition. The load balancers are attached like this

```
    lb = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(self, f'{resource_name_prefix}-lb',
      vpc=vpc.default_vpc,
      vpc_subnets=subnets.private_subnet_selection,
      internet_facing=False,
      security_group=security_groups.corp_security_group
    )

    listener = lb.add_listener('service_listener', port=80)

    listener.add_targets('c2-targets',
      port=80,
      targets=[
        self.fargate_service_definition.load_balancer_target(
          container_name='client',
          container_port=3000
        ),
        self.fargate_service_definition.load_balancer_target(
          container_name='server',
          container_port=4000
        )
      ]
    )
```

Am I missing something here? I've been combing through the cdk docs and it doesn't mention anything about explicitly stating that the service has a LB attached to it. I assumed it even set up a health check in the first place is because I added the LB at all. When I was testing without the LB, the cdk deployed perfectly fine

Comment: I'm having this exact problem. Were you able to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @rekans I ended up using ecs_patterns instead of alb. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs_patterns/ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html

I had 0 problems with integration after I started using ecs_patterns instead of ecs + alb

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot to use [register_load_balancer_targets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/FargateService.html#aws_cdk.aws_ecs.FargateService.register_load_balancer_targets) to actually associate your LB with the fargate service.

Comment: Doesn't the listener.add_targets associate the LB with the service?

Comment: and if it doesn't, could you explain what the difference between the two are?